# Do I capitalize course concentrations?

Tags: capitalization

We offer a Bachelor of Fine Arts degree with concentrations in Graphic Design, Painting, Sculpture, Photography, or Crafts and a Digital Media Arts degree with concentrations in Video or Animation.

Comment: Look in your college catalog and follow the practice found there.

Answer (score 1):

They could be considered titles and so that would be OK. Ether would work as long as you're consistent.